# make calculator with php

Tags: php, html, select

i want to make calculator with php and i wrote this code but doesn't worked  whats's the problem ? i use iclude to attach functions and use select and option tag and give options names to get data . i use phpstorm to solve problem but there were no problems . sorry for my bad English

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>


<body>
<form style="margin:25%;" action="#" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="num1" size="20" placeholder="number 1">
    <input type="text" name="num2" size="20" placeholder="number 2">

    <select name="massoud">
        <option name="jam1">jam</option>
        <option name="tafrigh1">tafrigh</option>
        <option name="zarb1">zarb</option>
        <option name="taghsim1">taghsim</option>
        <option name="baghimande1">baghimande</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="calculate">
</form>



<?php

include 'calib.php';

?>


<?php


if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['jam1'])) {


    $a1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $b1 = $_GET['num2'];



    echo jam1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['tafrigh1'])) {


    $a1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $b1 = $_GET['num2'];



    echo tafrigh1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['zarb1'])) {


    $a1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $b1 = $_GET['num2'];



    echo zarb1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['taghsim1'])) {


    $a1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $b1 = $_GET['num2'];



    echo taghsim1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['baghimande1'])) {


    $a1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $b1 = $_GET['num2'];



    echo baghimande1($a1, $b1);

}

?>



 </body>
 </html>
```

and this is include file

```
<?php

function jam1($a1, $b1){
return $a1 + $b1;
}
function tafrigh1($a1, $b1){
return $a1 - $b1;
}
function zarb1($a1, $b1){
return $a1 * $b1;
}
function taghsim1($a1, $b1){
return $a1 / $b1;
}
function baghimande1($a1, $b1){
return $a1 % $b1;
}

?>
```

this is the result url 
http://localhost/calib/?num1=6&num2=5&massoud=tafrigh&submit=calculate#

Comment: Please add logs to see where the program goes and doesn't, with which values in vars... you will learn lot more...

Comment: why it is not working

Comment: @PrashantTapase i don't know i use swith but won't work !

Comment: @Random http://localhost/calib/?num1=6&num2=5&massoud=tafrigh&submit=calculate#

Comment: @MaasoudAsadi We can't access a localhost website...

Comment: @Random use this http://massoudasadi.ir/calculator1/

Comment: check out answers, they should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

In each case you are asking for the exact value of the option rather than the value of the select which is what is posted:

```
 if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['jam1'])) {
```

There is no `$_GET['jam1']`, you should change this to your select name:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && ($_GET['massoud'] == 'jam1')) {
```

You need to add that to each of your cases

Edit: I didnt notice your select is also setup wrong:

```
<select name="massoud">
    <option name="jam1">jam</option>
    <option name="tafrigh1">tafrigh</option>
    <option name="zarb1">zarb</option>
    <option name="taghsim1">taghsim</option>
    <option name="baghimande1">baghimande</option>
</select>
```

You are setting the name of each option rather than the value, change to:

```
<select name="massoud">
    <option value="jam1">jam</option>
    <option value="tafrigh1">tafrigh</option>
    <option value="zarb1">zarb</option>
    <option value="taghsim1">taghsim</option>
    <option value="baghimande1">baghimande</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ive editing my answer as your select is also setup wrong as @bitWorking pointed out

Comment: it does, the source of that page still shows you are only setting the name of the options and not the values

Comment: It does, enter '2' and '2' in the boxes, select 'jam' and scroll to the bottom left,, '4' is displayed...

Comment: Glad to of wasted my time! @Tuhin Biswas said the same as everybody else 15 minutes later, didn't explain anything and didn't include the select option error

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['jam1'])) {
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['massoud']) && $_GET['massoud'] == 'jam1') {
```

jam1 is the value not the key. massoud is the name of the select dropdown and therefore the key.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<select name="massoud">
    <option value="jam1">jam</option>
    <option value="tafrigh1">tafrigh</option>
    <option value="zarb1">zarb</option>
    <option value="taghsim1">taghsim</option>
    <option value="baghimande1">baghimande</option>
</select>
```

And with `$_GET['massoud']` you get the selected value.

Comment: @Random It should be `<option value` and not `<option name`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and you will get your output at bottom left corner.

```
<?php


if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['massoud']) && $_GET['massoud'] == "jam") {


$a1 = $_GET['num1'];
$b1 = $_GET['num2'];



echo jam1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['massoud']) && $_GET['massoud'] == "tafrigh") {


$a1 = $_GET['num1'];
$b1 = $_GET['num2'];



echo tafrigh1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['massoud']) && $_GET['massoud'] == "zarb") {


$a1 = $_GET['num1'];
$b1 = $_GET['num2'];



echo zarb1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['massoud']) && $_GET['massoud'] == "taghsim") {


$a1 = $_GET['num1'];
$b1 = $_GET['num2'];



echo taghsim1($a1, $b1);

}

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['massoud']) && $_GET['massoud'] == "baghimande1") {


$a1 = $_GET['num1'];
$b1 = $_GET['num2'];



echo baghimande1($a1, $b1);

}

?>
```

Comment: Glad I am able to help you.